# Software to run on server checking outdated wordpress installations

Tags: plugins

Is there any software that I can run on either a Linux or a Windows server to check for domains that have out dated WordPress installations. I have seen a rise in hacked WordPress sites and in all the cases it was because the clients had not installed updates.

Comment: what about google webmaster tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the files from the server just include `wp-includes/version.php` from each installation. That file is completely stand-alone, it just defines five variables:

```
/**
 * The WordPress version string
 *
 * @global string $wp_version
 */
$wp_version = '3.5.1';

/**
 * Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB schema.
 *
 * @global int $wp_db_version
 */
$wp_db_version = 22441;

/**
 * Holds the TinyMCE version
 *
 * @global string $tinymce_version
 */
$tinymce_version = '358-23224';

/**
 * Holds the required PHP version
 *
 * @global string $required_php_version
 */
$required_php_version = '5.2.4';

/**
 * Holds the required MySQL version
 *
 * @global string $required_mysql_version
 */
$required_mysql_version = '5.0';
```

A simple [`version_compare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) will do the trick:

```
if ( '-1' == version_compare( $wp_version, '3.5.1' ) )
    return 'outdated';
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just use `wget` and grep the meta generator for example:

```
//need xml2 installed
wget -q -O - http://www.example.com | xml2 | grep meta | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

The problem is that a lot of people remove the meta `generator` tag, so then I suggest you have a look at this answer by Otto (the file he links ) on where else to check for version info, [Remotely identify the version of a WordPress installation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10626/remotely-identify-the-version-of-a-wordpress-installation)

There are also WordPress scanners that do version fingerprinting, namely WPScan, you can Google it.

If you have access to server files then toscho's answer is the best.